# Typing problems URLSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
const paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
const Search: string = searchParams.get("topic")?
searchParams.get("topic"):"100";
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:
Just store parameter value in variable (TypeScript doesn't implement a control flow based type analysis for function calls):

```
const topic = searchParams.get("topic");
const Search: string = topic ? topic : "100";
```

---

That's because [`URLSearch​Params​.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) returns `null` if search parameter is not found, so `searchParams.get("Search")` can be `null`.

You have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) compiler option enabled, hence the error.

To fix this, you can type variable as `string | null`:

```
const Search: string | null = searchParams.get("topic") 
  ? searchParams.get("Search")
  : "100";
```

Or if **you're sure** that query string has a "Search" parameter you can use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
const Search: string = searchParams.get("topic")
  ? searchParams.get("Search")!
  : "100";
```

Comment: searchParams.get("topic")?
searchParams.get("Search"):"100";but this line of the year cannot return null

Comment: Why not? it returns `null` currently (there's no "Search" param in your example)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just wrote the wrong code. I corrected. Look again.

Comment: @ Aleksey L. In your updated version, you explain the old version. In essence, you can use it to eliminate the error, but why an error occurs. If it is << const Search: string = searchParams.get ("topic")?
searchParams.get ("topic"): "100"; >> a line of code cannot pass type null?.

Comment: @Squanchy This is the explanation: _Typescript doesn't implement a control flow based type analysis for function calls_. `searchParams.get("topic")` is function call - typescript has no way to know that `searchParams.get` is a pure function and used with same parameter again